# Missing authorization_uri in WWW-Authorize header in Azure Function EasyAuth

Tags: powerbi, azure-functions, easy-auth

I have configured my Azure Function with the out of the box Azure AD identity provider. When an unauthenticated request is made, it is returning the WWW-Authenticate header showing the realm, but missing the authorization_uri. This makes it impossible to use the function using Organization Credentials in Power BI, which requires authorization_uri to be present.

[image: "New" EasyAuth/built-in auth 401 response]

I believe this is an issue related to the "new" built-in EasyAuth, since the "classic" EasyAuth returned much more information, including resource_id. I have an older function to demonstrate:

[image: "Classic" EasyAuth/built-in auth 401 response]

The only workaround I have tried is to [use Microsoft.Identity.Web in my Azure function code](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-implement-microsoft-identity-web-in-azure-functions-v4-and-net-6-7e6ef97b2926), but this is very hacky and adds a lot of complexity to otherwise simple code. EasyAuth keeps everything very simple and would work perfectly if it included more info in the WWW-Authenticate header.

How can I get a new Azure Function with EasyAuth enabled to return the authorization_uri in the WWW-Authenticate header in a 401 response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your Authentication settings -> Unauthenticated requests, if it's not "HTTP 302", then Azure will not return authorization_uri and other data.

[image]

Comment: This was in fact the answer! I just heard back from MS support too. I also had to use a custom domain name to get it to work in Power BI, since Power BI uses the realm to search for an app registration by Resource ID URI